# Div entering a floated tables content

Tags: html, css

I have the following example

```
<table align="right" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            test
        </td>
        <td>
             test
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             test
        </td>
        <td>
             test
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div style="width: 100%; background-color: red">
   test
</div>
```

If the code is run, the div will enter the floated table. The table will need to be floated so this can't change. Is there a way to stop the other content entering the floated element?

Comment: @MrLister: True, deleted my comment now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to give the table an explicit background color.

```
<table style="background:white; float:right" ...
```

See new [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pdkCR/2/).

The other answers all change other properties such as the relative widths or positions of the div and the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use depreciated HTML tags like align and border. Cellpadding and cellspacing can also be achieved with styles but I'll leave that as an exercise :) This will make the div take up as much space as is needed. If you know the size of the parent div which the table and this div are contained in, just set the width of the table and div to a fixed value.

```
<table style="float:right; border: 1px solid black;" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            test
        </td>
        <td>
             test
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             test
        </td>
        <td>
             test
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div style="float:left; background-color: red">
   test
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Shnjt/

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<div style="90%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<table style="float:right;width:45%">
</table>
<div style="width:45%;background-color: red; float:left;">
   test
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want div and table to be floated you need to set width for both and css: `float: left` to the div and `float: right` to the table.

Otherwise you can try removing `width:100%` from your `div` and adding `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a css property that controls whether an element respect the previous floating element.

Here is the documentation: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clear

I do not know what you want to get, but that might help.

Answer (score 0):

@ Mr.Lister....

```
    <div style="width: 100%; background-color: red;float:left;">
       test
    </div>
```

Float:left; will be helpful to your code.

Good Luck!